# Testing for negative values in a TreeMap

Tags: java

TreeMap Format:

```
TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> mapName = new TreeMap<>();
```

I'm trying to test the `ArrayList<Double>` for negative values. This is for a method so my string values aren't always consistent. I've tried to pull the values by using mapName.Values() but this is probably the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: Loop over the values, and then loop through the `List` and test for negative values

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know if there is a single negative number in the whole treeMap:

```
    mapName.values().stream()
             .flatMap(Collection::stream)
             .anyMatch(d -> d < 0);
```

If you want to put your hand on the lists which have at least one negative number:

```
    mapName.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().anyMatch(d -> d < 0))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```